# How do I create a mixin using less.js that doesn't output in the final stylesheet

Tags: css, frontend, less

I'm creating some mixins in my less.js stylesheets where I don't want the original mixin to appear in the final output.

For example, I have a couple of rules like this:

```
.grid1 { width: 960px; }
```

I'm then applying it to the element or elements I want to take those values like so:

```
.foo {
  .grid1;
}
```

But then my final css file has both in.

What facility does Less provide for creating the original mixin without rendering it as a css rule as well?

Answer (score 4):

The best answer I can come up with seems to be to declare the mixin as a parametric mixin or as part of a bundle, with or without no parameters.

e.g.

```
.grid1() { width: 960px; } /* Not rendered in final css */
```

as opposed to

```
.grid1 { width: 960px; } /* Will render */
```

(note lack of parentheses)

Feels a bit of a hack, but I'm not sure why the language should have something special for that purpose if this does the trick.