# Less inherit "virtual" class

Tags: css, styles, less

I am using SASS and there is nice feature: I can create "fake/virtual" class and then use it for extend.
Example:

```
%myFakeClass
{
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#000;
}

.myRealClass
{
   @extend %myFakeClass;
}

.myRealClass2
{
   @extend %myFakeClass;
}
```

Output:

```
.myRealClass, .myRealClass2
{
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#000;
}
```

**The question:**
Does LESS has something similar? In other words, I want to create a "virtual class" that I can inherit from, but the "virtual class" itself not exists in output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Not Directly as of Yet

As of this date (11-22-2013) there is still a [feature request](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1177) that would allow this by doing extending on empty parameter mixins (which do not output css themselves). So ***eventually*** something like this would be possible (which mirrors almost exactly what you want):

```css
.myFakeClass() {
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#000;
}

.myRealClass {
   &:extend(.myFakeClass);
}

.myRealClass2 {
   &:extend(.myFakeClass);
}
```

***And output as you expect.***

### Workaround for now

This was mentioned by Bass Jobsen, but not explicitly demonstrated. In LESS 1.5, you build a file for your fake classes, say `fakeClasses.less`, which for our example has this in it:

```css
.myFakeClass {
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#000;
}
```

Then in your file that you want to extend to it, let's say `styles.less`, you do this:

```css
@import (reference) fakeClasses.less;

.myRealClass {
   &:extend(.myFakeClass);
}

.myRealClass2 {
   &:extend(.myFakeClass);
}
```

This will import the `fakeClasses.less` classes but NOT compile them to css (so they are "fake" within the context of `styles.less`, but "real" in that they *can* be extended to), and you will ***get the output you expect***.

```
.myRealClass, .myRealClass2 {
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following helps you `img { &:extend(.img-responsive); }` from [Why gives Grunt / Recess an error and Lessc not when compiling Bootstrap 3 RC1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935703/why-gives-grunt-recess-an-error-and-lessc-not-when-compiling-boostrap-3-rc1)

**update** from [How do I create a mixin using less.js that doesn't output in the final stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994865/how-do-i-create-a-mixin-using-less-js-that-doesnt-output-in-the-final-styleshee):

```
.myFakeClass()
{
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#000;
}

.myRealClass, .myRealClass2
{
   .myFakeClass();
}
```

since LESS 1.5 you could also place you virtual classes in a separate file and use:
`@import (reference) "file.less";`

> We have another import option - reference. This means that any
>   variables or mixins or selectors will be imported, but never output.

Comment: This is not what I looking for. What you suggest, will require me manually add each selector to the list of classes that use .myFakeClass()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if `@extend` works the same as a "mixin", but it looks the same.

```
.myFakeClass(@textColor: #fff, @bgColor: #000 )
{
  color:@textColor;
  background-color:@bgColor;
}

.myRealClass
{
   .myFakeClass();
}

.myRealClass2
{
   .myFakeClass();
}
```

The out put for this would be the same as what you have above. I added variables in the mixin for easier customization for this mixin.

Example:

```
.myRealClass3
{
   .myFakeClass(#369, #00f);
}
```

The output for all three classes would be:

```
.myRealClass, .myRealClass2
{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
}

.myRealClass3
{
   color:#369;
   background-color:#00f;
}
```

Like I said, I'm not entirely sure if there is a big difference between extending a class in SASS and using a mixin in LESS. Hope this helps either way.

---

Oh, and just to clarify, if the `.myFakeClass()` class is in a separate .less file that is imported, it will not show up in your CSS unless it is used. I tested this on a website I'm building. I have:

```
.box-shadow(@a, @b, etc..) {
    box-shadow: @a @b etc..;
    -webkit-box-shadow: @a @b etc..;
    etc: @a...;
 }
```

The class `.box-shadow` does not show up in my CSS at all.

Link: http://lucienconsulting.com/gs-news/wp-content/themes/TheStone/css/style.css

However, if you write a mixin like this:

```
.myMixin{
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

It will show up like a normal class even if not used. Obviously, it looks just like a normal class and could be used by itself, or as a mixin, like so:

```
.myClass{
   .myMixin;
   border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

This would compile to:

```
.myClass{
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

It works, but `.myMixin` would also show up in your style sheet in this case.

But, like I said, in my original example, it would not.